# Libgit2 custom odb backend

Tags: git, libgit2

I would like to create a note-taking tool (both local and web version) which would have support for versioning and efficient search (gin index seems to be perfect). Do you know a way to have a git server that saves file data in postgresql (or another DBMS)?
Otherwise, I'm trying to implement a SQL database in libgit2 but I'm lost on what to do. Do you know of a project (even an extremely basic one) implementing a custom ODB backend for libgit2 with a usage example in any language?
Currently, I am trying thanks to https://github.com/libgit2/libgit2-backends

Comment: Recommendations for tools, libraries, etc. lead to opinion based answers and therefore are off-topic on SO.